# Can "pip" mean picture or icon in British English?

Tags: american-english, british-english, slang, translation

I am playing a British game and I'm having trouble exactly understanding some of the words used in the dialogs!

[image: faded pip!?]
*from "godus" game*

They seem to use the word "pip" to mean "graphic" or "icon", but I want to know if "pip" can be synonymous with "image" or "icon" or "graphic" in British English. I can't seem to find any definitions meaning that in Google's dictionary -- [Google has](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Apip):

pip:

1. a small hard seed in a fruit.
2. [US] an excellent or very attractive person or thing

"An excellent or very attractive person or thing" seems too general to be intended, while I don't think the picture is supposed one of a fruit seed?

What is an equivalent American English word to "pip" in the graphic shown?

Comment: As a speaker of BrE, I can't say I've ever read/heard this usage of the word.

Comment: Neither have I. I could have sworn it _pip_ meant fruit seed.

Comment: I have seen pip used to describe a small icon or graphic on some sort of computer (which includes e.g. an avionics heads-up display), usually describing your current or future position or perhaps the target point of your guns. I can't find a source, but I believe carrier-based pilots use the phrase 'keep the pip on the ball' whilst landing. (I can't find a ref because in the UK any search including pip seems to be hijacked by a government allowance called 'Personal Independence Payment'). I would guess that it's called a pip because it's small and round, just like a fruit pip.

Comment: I dunno if it's connected to your question, but the marks on dice and playing cards that indicate the value of face or card are called [pips](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(counting)).

Comment: There have been many requests that people not "cite 'Google Dictionary' " on ELU. The dictionary is actually [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/pip#:~:targetText=noun,has%20nasty%20pips%20in%20it.), and if one looks at the second, totally different word _pip_ defined below, one finds: << pip 2 NOUN
1British A star (one to three according to rank) on the shoulder of an army officer's uniform.

2Any of the spots on a playing card, dice, or domino.

3An image of an object on a radar screen ...>>.

Comment: Voting to close.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey why? There is a comment above that offers a _very_ surprisingly good answer to this question

Comment: @simonatrcl if you post that as an answer I would accept it

Comment: @bobobobo Thanks, but I've got no references so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In informal British or American English, pip is a disc or diamond of rank worn on the shoulder of British officers or American cadets.  It's also another word for a spot (spade, diamond, club, heart) on a playing card.  So, it has a generic meaning outside computer graphics.  I take pip in the example as plain English/American.

Comment: This would be my answer; but it does not seem American to this American.

Comment: You'd only know of them if you went to an American military school.